# Display (and pass) a custom user field in php

Tags: entities

In Drupal 7, I've added some custom fields in Account Settings>Manage Fields.  One of them is field_company_name.  I'd like to be able to display this field and pass it to an external php function.

I can easily display the $user fields for the current user.  For example:

```
<?php
global $user;
echo 'Current User: ';
print_r($user->name);
echo '<br/>User ID: ';
print_r($user->uid);
echo '<br/>Email Address: ';
print_r($user->mail);
echo '<br/>'
?>
```

How to I get at field_company_name for this same user?

Answer (score 2):

You need to load the user object up fully with [`user_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load/7), so the fields get attached:

```
$account = user_load($GLOBALS['user']->uid);
```

Then use [`field_get_items()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) to extract the field data:

```
if ($items = field_get_items('user', $account, 'field_company_name')) {
  $company_name = $items[0]['value'];
}
```

Comment: It's a week later and, thanks in good measure to your help, I'm about 1000 miles farther down the road. Thanks!  I'm down to one last thing before being able to wrap this up:  How would I update one of these custom fields in php?  Say I needed to push a value into $company_name in our example.